# Can Sisyphus deal with a page which is displayed by ID?

Tags: javascript

[Sisyphus](http://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/) is a plugin that deals with auto saving of forms in local storage.

It works pretty well on first look. What I want to know, is it possible to use with a dynamic page driven by an ID.

eg: MyPage/1 and MyPage/2 (MVC url's but could equally be querystrings), such that the page is rendered, maybe bringing some value back from a database, rendering some unique controls.

In other words, can Sisyphus deal with a parameterised page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's actually really easy.

We can use the locationBased option as per [documentation](http://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/#customization)

```
 $("form").sisyphus({
            locationBased: true
        });
```